# Saving the value from a drop-down list

Tags: php, html, variables, drop-down-menu

Here's my situation, I have 2 pages, one for selecting a value and one for editing database related things which are associated to that value.

Right now, I have no knowledge ( and have researched a fair bit ) on how to save the value selected from the drop down list into a variable from PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a form with the drop down, which you then submit to your PHP script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its two step:
First html:

```
<form action='databasethings.php' method=post>
<select name="myvalue">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Its for sending the value to databasethings.php script.(

Then in databasethings.php:

```
$myvalue=$_POST['myvalue'];
//do something with myvalue
```

This will catch value1, 2 or 3 from html into $myvalue in php

Answer (score 8):

HTML:

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">
<select id="drop" name="drop">
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

page.php:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['drop'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are submitting a form to the page for editing database related things. On that page use $_REQUEST['the_name_of_the_select_box']

```
    <select name="the_name_of_the_select_box">
```

the select value will be in

```
    $_REQUEST['the_name_of_the_select_box'] or  $_POST['the_name_of_the_select_box']
```

Answer (score 0):

might like this

```
$('element').change(function(){
               $.ajax({
                    url:"savepage",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:({}),
                    dataType:"html", // json // xml
                    async:false,
                    success: function(msg){
                        alert(msg); // get result
                    }
                });
});
```